# Machine epsilon on C

Tags: c, floating-point

Why do the two `printf` statements in the following print the same value if the `(float)` cast is present but not if it is removed?

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float eps = 1.0;
    while ((float)(1 + eps/2.0) != 1.0)
        eps /= 2.0;

    printf("%e\n", eps);
    printf("%e\n", FLT_EPSILON);
}
```

Comment: How do you define that the code "works" or does "not work"?

Comment: post a [mcve] ( which this is not), expected output, error you are getting.

Comment: Chalk up another unsuspecting victim of  [`FLT_EVAL_METHOD==1`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.2p9), I think.

Comment: Oh come on people, the difference between this and an actual MCVE is not worth jumping down a new poster's throat over.  Look: <https://godbolt.org/z/Mosxbazj3>

Comment: I _would_ bet a cookie this is a duplicate, but I'm not having any luck finding one.

Comment: @zwol: It is not the evaluation method. `1 + eps/2.0` is a `double` expression, so the loop without the cast detects the `double` epsilon. (Floating-point evaluation could screw that up, so that it detects the `long double` epsilon, but that is not the issue here; the issue is using `double` types when `float` is desired.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh, right, `2.0` vs `2.0f`, read rIght past that.  Comes to the same thing though.

Comment: @harrypotter: If you want a question answered, you need to pose it properly. For a question like this, that means including code that can be compiled cleanly without any insertions or changes and it means clearly stating what the issue is. (“work” is not an adequate description of what code is expected to do). The fact the question is close does not mean it will not be answered; it means, in this case, the question needs improvement before it will be reopened and is eligible for answering. If you want other people to help you, expect to be in some work yourself.

Answer (score 8):

As programming languages go, C is unusually happy to do arithmetic in a wider type than you might have expected it to.  In this case, the expression

```
eps/2.0
```

converts `eps` to `double` before the division, because the numeric constant `2.0` has type `double`.  You can avoid that by writing `2.0f` instead, but even then, there is a rule that says the compiler is allowed to do *all* floating-point arithmetic in `double` or even `long double` as long as the choice is documented. ([C2011 section 5.2.4.2.2, paragraph 9](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.2).)

With an implementation where `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 0`, you can avoid casts by writing instead

```
    float eps = 1.0f;
    while (1.0f + eps/2.0f != 1.0f)
        eps /= 2.0f;
```

but if `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` is nonzero, the cast you had is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

**Save time, enable all warnings**

With OP's code a well enabled compiler reports something like

```
warning: conversion from 'double' to 'float' may change value [-Wfloat-conversion]  
eps /= 2.0;
```

and so hints that something is going on between `float` and `double`.

**`double` or wider intermediate math**

Using `double` constants or depending on `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`, various results are possible.  `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 2` implies intermediate FP math may be done using `long double` range and precision.

---

Moral of the story: be careful when using floating point math.

```
int main(void) {
  printf("FLT_EVAL_METHOD %d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);
  printf("FLT_EPSILON     %e\n", FLT_EPSILON);
  puts("");

  {
    float eps = 1.0;
    while ((float) (1 + eps / 2.0) != 1.0) // Cast and double math
      eps /= 2.0;
    printf("%e\n", eps);
  }

  {
    float eps = 1.0;
    while ((1 + eps / 2.0) != 1.0)  // No cast, double
      eps /= 2.0;
    printf("%e\n", eps);
  }

  {
    float eps = 1.0;
    while ((1.0f + eps / 2.0f) != 1.0f)  // No cast, float
      eps /= 2.0f;
    printf("%e\n", eps);
  }

  {
    float eps = 1.0;
    for(;;) {
      float oneplus = 1.0f + eps/2.0f; // Coerce float math
      if (oneplus == 1.0f) break;
      eps /= 2.0f;
    }
    printf("%e\n", eps);
  }
}
```

Output with `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 0`

```
FLT_EVAL_METHOD 0
FLT_EPSILON     1.192093e-07

1.192093e-07  // Cast, double math
2.220446e-16  // No cast, double  math
1.192093e-07  // No cast, float math
1.192093e-07  // No cast, Coerced float math
```

Output with `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 2`

```
FLT_EVAL_METHOD 2
FLT_EPSILON     1.192093e-07

1.192093e-07
1.084202e-19  // No cast, long double  math
1.084202e-19  // No cast, long double  math
1.192093e-07
```

**Rounding mode**

Rounding mode may affect things, yet I do not yet have a sample to demo it.